# Reading X11 properties

Tags: bash, x11, python

I want to write my own status bar, that would be EWMH compatible, which means I have to read some X11 properties like:

```
    _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS
    _NET_DESKTOP_NAMES
```

and such. So my question is how do I actually read them? Have already tried `python-xlib` and `python-ewmh` modules but with no luck. Maybe there's a command line utility that I don't know of. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `xprop -root` is what you are looking for:

```
xprop -root _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS
```

produces the output:

```
_NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS(CARDINAL) = 4
```

and respectively

```
xprop -root _NET_DESKTOP_NAMES
```

produces the output:

```
_NET_DESKTOP_NAMES(UTF8_STRING) = "Desktop 1", "Desktop 2", "Desktop 3", "Desktop 4"
```

At least in Debian, the command is within the `x11-utils` package.